# doctrine2 - how to use DATE_ADD function

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to use the `DATE_ADD` function from doctrine2 but I am having trouble get it right.

I am using like this in DQL:

```
->andWhere('p.created_at <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),4, day)')
```

but I am getting syntax error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 215: Error: Expected'.' or '(', got 'day'

I tried different implementations but I allways get some kind of syntax errror.

I have checked DoctrineExtensions which contain this function, but I shouldnt need it because the function is already included in doctrine.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have a typo, you have to quotes 'day'

```
->andWhere("p.created_at <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),4, 'day')")
```

An example [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1293?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel).

Comment: If you replace all `'` with `"` and vice versa (like: `>andWhere('p.created_at <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),4, "day")')` )it would not work.